# Keep getting invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' error

Tags: python

I don't understand, I keep getting this error for "x[j][i]=int(line[i])" code... Been looking for 2 days, please help me. I don't get what's the problem just trying to do a sudoku. Thanks for the help.

```
def charge(nom_du_fichier):
    mon_fichier=open(nom_du_fichier,"r")
    x=[[0]*9 for i in range (9)]
    for j in range(9) :
        line=mon_fichier.readline().split(" ")
    for i in range(len(line)):
        x[j][i]=int(line[i])
    return(x)


g=charge("sudoku.txt")
```

Comment: First of all can you format your code ? It's not well formated.

Comment: Clearly, whatever is in `line[i]` is not  convertable to an `int`, so what does your file look like?

Comment: All you have to do is insert a line `print(line)` before `for i in range...`.  When you see a traceback look just at what appears just before it.  Then you will know exactly what the content of `line` is that's causing the problem.

Comment: The `sudoku.txt` file is probably not looking like you expect it. You should post some lines from it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your file format, whitespace, newlines and many other characters will not convert to ints using the int() function. Maybe instead try:

```
def charge(nom_du_fichier):
    mon_fichier=open(nom_du_fichier,"r")
    x=[[0]*9 for i in range (9)]
    for j in range(9) :
        line=mon_fichier.readline().split(" ")
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if line[i].isdigit():
            x[j][i]=int(line[i])
        else:
            #either pass or deal with unused data
    return(x)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new and I really suck at it. I though that my codes would work but I'm still having errors and the file doesn't look like how I want it to be. Thanks for helping a lost cause like me.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere :)